# How to create ExpressJS PDF Template 'if statements'

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, pdf-generation

Does anyone know how to create if statements in a PDF template with expressjs when creating a PDF? For example, something like the following snippet inside a pdf-index.ejs template file:

```
<body>
    <% if($src === 'invoice'){ %>

        <%- include('./pdf-invoice.ejs') %>

    <% } else if($src === 'contract'){ %>

        <%- include('./pdf-contract.ejs') %>

    <% } %>
</body>
```

Note: the above **does not** work with EJS when creating a PDF

Answer (score 0):

I am using `html-pdf` npm package for generating pdf from html

```
const template = (params) =>{

return(`

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
You can use if statement this way ${
  if(params == "hello"){
    return "1"
  }
}

</body>
</html>`
}



module.exports = template
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.